# Using a list as replacement for singular patterns in regexp_replace

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that I need to delete random words/characters out of. To do this, I have been using a regexp_replace function with the addition of multiple patterns. An example is below:

```
select regexp_replace(combined,'\y(NAME|001|CONTAINERS:|MT|COUNT|PCE|KG|PACKAGE)\y','', 'g')
as description, id from export_final;
```

However, in the full list, there are around 70 different patterns that I replace out of the description. As you can imagine, the code if very cluttered: This leads me to my question. Is there a way to put these patterns into another table then use that table to check the descriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Populate your desired 'other' table with what patterns you need. Then create a CTE that uses string_agg function to build the regex. Example:

```
create table exclude_list( pattern_word text);

insert into exclude_list(pattern_word) 
   values('NAME'),('001'),('CONTAINERS:'),('MT'),('COUNT'),('PCE'),('KG'),('PACKAGE');

with exclude as 
     ( select '\y(' || string_agg(pattern_word,'|') || ')\y' regex from exclude_list )

    -- CTE simulates actual table to provide test data
   , export_final (id,combined) as (values (0,'This row 001 NAME Main PACKAGE has COUNT 3 units'),(1,'But single package can hold 6 KG')) 

select regexp_replace(combined,regex,'', 'g')
    as description, id 
  from export_final cross join exclude;
```